# How can I identify the two smallest values (and indexes) rolling over a column in R?

Tags: r, data.table, vectorization, rolling-computation

I have been looking for an answer to this question for days.  I think I am very close, but I cannot figure how to do the rolling piece of it.

I have a data.table with two columns like this:

```
df = data.table(a = c(8,3,6,12,15,21,4,5,1,32,13), b = c(12,3,1,66,4,7,32,6,76,2,11))
```

I would like to obtain the smallest two values and their indexes on a rolling four day window.  Rfast::nth seems to give me everything I need except I cannot vectorize it.  Obviously I am doing something wrong.

I need the output to look as follows:

```
     a  b low lowIdx low2 low2Idx
 1:  8 12  NA     NA   NA      NA
 2:  3  3  NA     NA   NA      NA
 3:  6  1  NA     NA   NA      NA
 4: 12 66   3      2    6       3
 5: 15  4   3      1    6       2
 6: 21  7   6      1    12      2
 7:  4 32   4      4    12      1
 8:  5  6   4      3    4       3
 9:  1 76   1      4    4       2
10: 32  2   1      3    4       1
11: 13 11   1      2    5       1
```

I have attempted this with different forms of the following:

```
n <- nrow(df)
df$low[4:n] <- Rfast::nth(df[(n-3):n]$a, 1)
df$lowIdx[4:n] <- Rfast::nth(df$a, 1, index.return = TRUE)
df$low2[4:n] <- Rfast::nth(df[(n-3):n]$a, 2)
df$low2Idx[4:n] <- Rfast::nth(df$a, 2, index.return = TRUE)
```

I have also been trying to work with the frollapply, but to no avail.

Thank you, Pete

Comment: `low2` and `low2Idx` are the second lowest value and index, right? Why their value in row 8 is the same?

Comment: Ronak, yes that is correct, low2 and low2Idx are the second lowest value and index.  Thank you everyone for the help!

Comment: Also, this will ultimately be against multiple cols for 11 million records.  I will do some timings and report what is the fastest.  Thanks again for the help everyone.

Comment: ```Rfast``` also has ```colnth``` which is what you want.

Answer (score 2):

Library `runner` also helps.

```
library(dplyr)
library(runner)
df %>% mutate(low = runner(x=a, k=4, f = function(x) ifelse(length(x) ==4, min(x), NA)),
              lowIdx = runner(x = a, k =4, function(x) ifelse(length(x) ==4, which.min(x), NA)),
              Low2 = runner(x=a, k=4, f = function(x) ifelse(length(x) ==4, sort(x)[2], NA)),
              Low2Idx =runner(x=a, k=4, f = function(x) ifelse(length(x) ==4, order(x)[2], NA))
              )

     a  b low lowIdx Low2 Low2Idx
 1:  8 12  NA     NA   NA      NA
 2:  3  3  NA     NA   NA      NA
 3:  6  1  NA     NA   NA      NA
 4: 12 66   3      2    6       3
 5: 15  4   3      1    6       2
 6: 21  7   6      1   12       2
 7:  4 32   4      4   12       1
 8:  5  6   4      3    5       4
 9:  1 76   1      4    4       2
10: 32  2   1      3    4       1
11: 13 11   1      2    5       1
```

Comment: I used this one in my code.  I understand it a bit better and I did not have to deal with different time frames for the dates.

Answer (score 1):

With `frollapply` in `data.table` you can do :

```
library(data.table)

cols <- c('low', 'lowIdx', 'low2', 'low2Idx')
n <- 4
df[, (cols)  := .(frollapply(a, n, min), 
                  frollapply(a, n, which.min), 
                  frollapply(a, n, function(x) sort(x)[2]), 
                  frollapply(a, n, function(x) order(x)[2]))]
df

#     a  b low lowIdx low2 low2Idx
# 1:  8 12  NA     NA   NA      NA
# 2:  3  3  NA     NA   NA      NA
# 3:  6  1  NA     NA   NA      NA
# 4: 12 66   3      2    6       3
# 5: 15  4   3      1    6       2
# 6: 21  7   6      1   12       2
# 7:  4 32   4      4   12       1
# 8:  5  6   4      3    5       4
# 9:  1 76   1      4    4       2
#10: 32  2   1      3    4       1
#11: 13 11   1      2    5       1
```

Answer (score 0):

For a simple example like yours I suggest using `frollapply`. For better control of the window, especially if you have gaps in a dates column I recommend [runner](https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=runner). See the [documentation](https://gogonzo.github.io/runner/) for more

```r
df[, c('low', 'lowIdx', 'low2', 'low2Idx')  := .(
  min_run(a, k = 4, na_pad = TRUE), 
  runner(a, k = 4, function(x) ifelse(length(x) > 0, which.min(x), NA), na_pad = TRUE), 
  runner(a, k = 4, function(x) sort(x)[2], na_pad = TRUE), 
  runner(a, k = 4, function(x) order(x)[2], na_pad = TRUE)
)]
df
#      a  b low lowIdx low2 low2Idx
#  1:  8 12  NA     NA   NA      NA
#  2:  3  3  NA     NA   NA      NA
#  3:  6  1  NA     NA   NA      NA
#  4: 12 66   3      2    6       3
#  5: 15  4   3      1    6       2
#  6: 21  7   6      1   12       2
#  7:  4 32   4      4   12       1
#  8:  5  6   4      3    5       4
#  9:  1 76   1      4    4       2
# 10: 32  2   1      3    4       1
# 11: 13 11   1      2    5       1
```

Comment: Runner is really a useful package.  Your answer is very similar to mine.  Actually I am a fan of your package. :)